# Mod_rewrite - change .htaccess into httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have following .htaccess rules which removing .php extension in urls from domain.com/index.php to domain.com/index/ and working fine

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now I want to use httpd.conf file instead of .htaccess, but when I try rewrite it to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

url is rewritten correctly to domain.com/index/, but server returns error 404.

I'll be glad for any help and suggestions, what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is already full filesystem path if file or directory is found so prefixing that with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` will make an invalid path.

You can use these rules in `httpd.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'll try it

Comment: Oh I had missed one `/` after `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` (corrected now).

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I have to wait to morning until tech support will save changes to httpd.conf file, so I'll be in touch after about 8 hours.

Comment: I tried it, but these rules unfortunately doesn't work (.php extension doesn't disappear and I think that because of some small syntax error whole file doesn't work)

Comment: Check my updated answer. I've tested these rules inside my `vhost.conf` file and everything works as expected. `.php` file must exist in your `DocumentRoot`. If it doesn't work check your Apache error.log or enable `RewriteLog` and check rewrite log file.