# Move .htaccess wordpress directives to apache config file

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to avoid .htaccess files in WordPress. I tried to move all directives to an apache config file, enclosing them into  tags, but it doesn't work.

I'm using Apache/2.4.37

My current config at apache is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb
    ServerName myweb.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog logs/myweb.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/myweb.com-access_log common

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certificate/myweb.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certificate/myweb.key

    <Directory "/var/www/html/myweb">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way to avoid .htaccess rewrites?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400674/mod-rewrite-change-htaccess-into-httpd-conf-file

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that there are some slight differences in the situation when you move the code.

1. `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` does not make sense in the global configuration, since RewriteRules work on *absolute path* there as opposed to distributed configuration files where they work on *relative paths* ... So it should be `RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]` instead, note the leading slash.
2. `RewriteBase /` does not make any sense in the global configuration, remove that one.
3. Move the code block *outside* the `<Directory ...>...</Directory>` block. The rules should get applied globally.
4. You *could* replace the `L` flag with the `END` flag. You may want to take a look into the documentation about that.

*And* you need to take care that wordpress is happy even if it can *not* mess around with configuration files.